# Randomly move (and rotate) an sf polygon within a broader extent using R

Tags: r, sf

I have an area of interest within which I have multiple polygons (two in the example below). I would like to randomly move each of the polygons so that they are completely within the larger extent and do not overlap the original placement. I am working within `sf`.

Using the `nc` simple feature, we can run the following:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

#Make outline extent
Extent <- nc %>% 
  mutate(State = "NC") %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  summarize()

#Make two polygons
Poly <- nc %>% 
  filter(NAME %in% c("Wilkes", "Greene"))
```

As reproducible example, I would like to randomly move both the "Wilkes" and "Greene" polygons within the `Extent`. It is fine if the new location of "Wilkes" overlaps the old or new (random) location of "Green" but the random location of "Wikles" should not overlap the old location of "Wikels".

The end result would be an sf multipolygon with 4 polygons, the two originals and the two random placements (ideally within the same "Name" grouping, but with a separate field delineated which is original and which is random).

[image]

Comment: Depends on your idea of "random". The most "random" would be to sample with uniform probability from the continuum of all possible placements of translated/rotated polygon X within Y that do not overlap original X. That is hard. Alternatively, you could iterate over random shifts and rotations until you find something that satisfies your intersection condition. These are different processes.

Comment: @Spaceman the 2nd option would suffice for this work. How might I randomly shift or rotate the polygon as you suggested? Any suggestions with the included example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unless there's an sf-native solution, I'd convert to sp object (`library(sp); P = as(Poly, "Spatial")` and similar) then use `maptools::elide(P, shift=c(dx, dy), rotate=theta)` to move each one, then use `rgeos` methods to test intersection then if no intersection convert back to `sf` with `st_as_sf(P)`.

Comment: @Spaceman I am open to `sp` if you want to post as answer.